# knockout problems with hover

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, hover, mouseover

I am using knockout to bind some data. What is working pretty well. But now I need to bind some data, and when the user passes the mouse over this should display a message with some info.

```
**My CSS:**

.message{
    display:none;
    color:#000;
    background:#999;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
}

.mo:hover .message{
    background-color: yellow !important;
    display:block !important;
    z-index:10;
}
```

**my html for message:**

```
function getGrayStatus() {
        return "<a  href='#'>" +
            "<span class='mo' style='background-color:gray; padding-left: 100%;'>" +
            "<p class='message'><b>my message</b></p>" +
            "</span>" +
            "</a>";
}
```

**js bind code:**

```
 main.sellers.push(
    {
        sellerCode: "1", totalClientsInRoute: "45", visitedClientsInRoute : "32",
        notVisitedClientsInRout: "2", clientsWithSaleInRoute: "1",
        percentageOfClientsWithSalesInRoute: "15", visitsOutOfPointInRoute: "1",
        totalClientsOutOfRoute: "11", clientsWithSaleOutOfRoute: "15",
        sales: [{ sale: getRedStatus() }, { sale: getGreenStatus() }, { sale: getGrayStatus() }}
```

**Bind in html:**

```
 <div class="dashboard-sellers-table-sales">
     <div class="table-row" data-bind="foreach: sales">
        <div class="table-cell" data-bind="html: sale"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The bindings are working. The problem is that message isn't showed. If we make a test without knockout the message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how's your entire model's code but here is a working example of your snippet code.
https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/151/

**view:**

```
 <!-- ko foreach: ItemList -->
  <div class="dashboard-sellers-table-sales">
       <div class="table-row" data-bind="foreach: sales">
          <div class="table-cell" data-bind="html: sale"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

**JS:**

```
var MainViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.ItemList = ko.observableArray([{
        sellerCode: "1", totalClientsInRoute: "45", visitedClientsInRoute : "32",
        notVisitedClientsInRout: "2", clientsWithSaleInRoute: "1",
        percentageOfClientsWithSalesInRoute: "15", visitsOutOfPointInRoute: "1",
        totalClientsOutOfRoute: "11", clientsWithSaleOutOfRoute: "15",
        sales: [{ sale: getRedStatus() }, { sale: getGreenStatus() }, { sale: getGrayStatus() }]
    }]);
}

var ItemViewModel = function(data){
 var self = this;
   self.sellerCode = data.sellerCode;
   self.totalClientsInRoute = data.totalClientsInRoute;
   self.visitedClientsInRoute = data.visitedClientsInRoute;
   self.notVisitedClientsInRout = data.notVisitedClientsInRout;
   self.clientsWithSaleInRoute = data.clientsWithSaleInRoute;
   self.percentageOfClientsWithSalesInRoute = data.percentageOfClientsWithSalesInRoute;
   self.visitsOutOfPointInRoute = data.visitsOutOfPointInRoute;
   self.totalClientsOutOfRoute = data.totalClientsOutOfRoute;
   self.clientsWithSaleOutOfRoute = data.clientsWithSaleOutOfRoute;
   self.sales = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.sales($.map(data.sales, function (item) {
      return new SalesItemViewModel(item);
    }));
}

var SalesItemViewModel = function(data){
  var self = this;
  self.sale = data.sale;
}
var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

function getGrayStatus() {
        return "<a  href='#'>" +
            "<span class='mo' style='background-color:gray; padding-left: 100%;'>" +
            "<p class='message'><b>my GRAY message</b></p>" +
            "</span>" +
            "</a>";
}
function getRedStatus() {
        return "<a  href='#'>" +
            "<span class='mo-red' style='background-color:red; padding-left: 100%;'>" +
            "<p class='message'><b>my RED message</b></p>" +
            "</span>" +
            "</a>";
}
function getGreenStatus() {
        return "<a  href='#'>" +
            "<span class='mo-green' style='background-color:green; padding-left: 100%;'>" +
            "<p class='message'><b>my GREEN message</b></p>" +
            "</span>" +
            "</a>";
}
```